# Plugin “Hello World!” for User onUserAuthorisation

Tags: php, events, plugins, joomla

I am trying to create a plugin to make some database queries from the [event onUserAuthorisation](https://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events/User#onUserAuthorisation).  Right now I am just trying to set up a "Hello World" style plugin, because I am not sure yet that my plugin function is even firing correctly.  Right now the plugin should just send out an email when a new user gains authorisation.

I can confirm that the joomla emails work for user registration and administration.

Files: `autoextranet.php`,`autoextranet.xml`,`index.html`(empty)

autoextranet.php

```
<?php

// no direct access
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

class plgUserAutoextranet extends JPlugin
{
    public function onUserAuthorisation($user, $options)
        {
        $mailer = JFactory::getMailer();
        $config = JFactory::getConfig();

        $sender = array( 
            $config->get( 'mailfrom' ),
            $config->get( 'fromname' )
            );
        $mailer->setSender($sender);

        $recipient = array( 'email1@gmail.com', 'email2@some.com' );
        $mailer->addRecipient($recipient);

        $body = "New User: ".$user->username;
        $mailer->setBody($body);

        $mailer->setSubject('You got a new user.');

        $mailer->Send();
        }
}

?>
```

autoextranet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<extension version="3.8.2" type="plugin" group="user">
        <name>PLG_USER_AUTOEXTRANET</name>
        <author>Tim DeLise</author>
        <creationDate>Nov 14, 2017</creationDate>
        <copyright>Tim D</copyright>
        <license>GNU General Public License</license>
        <authorEmail>your email</authorEmail>
        <authorUrl>your website</authorUrl>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <description>.</description>
        <files>
                <filename plugin="autoextranet">autoextranet.php</filename>
                <filename>index.html</filename>
        </files>
</extension>
```

The problem now is that I have installed and activated the plugin.  When I create and activate a new user, I just get nothing.

Unfortunately I have limited access to the server, and haven't been able to view the PHP error logs.  I am looking for some way to confirm that the event is firing my code.  Any suggestion is welcome.  Also this is the first plugin I am making so maybe there is something wrong with my files.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Joomla Version 3.8.2

Comment: Does it work on your local dev environment?

Comment: @SvenBluege that is a great point.

Comment: I realized that the this event doesn't fire until the user actually tries to log in to the site.  When I was testing I wasn't completing the last step, so the event wasn't triggering.

Comment: So I'll add this as a solution :)

Comment: The best way to test if an event is firing is to have it put some text somewhere either by logging or by displaying something.  Adding in the email system is adding a layer of complexity you don't need for that purpose.

Answer (score 1):

The function `onUserAuthorisation` is triggered once the user is in the login process. Make sure you really log in to Joomla :)

I'm sure you're aware of this. But this function is triggered even if the login fails.